Integrate GraphQL api in GoFr framework in golang
I want to integrate the GraphQL API Support in our golang framework GoFr(https://gofr.dev)
I used this package for the same: https://github.com/graph-gophers/graphql-go
My task was to integrate the GraphQL in GoFr which currently supports the http and gRPC protocol.
I modified the http-Server to include the graphQL handler and made a new file graphql.go that contains the ServeHTTP method.
Branch: https://github.com/gofr-dev/gofr/tree/en/graphQL_support
File link: https://github.com/gofr-dev/gofr/blob/en/graphQL_support/pkg/gofr/graphql.go
Currently I integrated the support and made this example:
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gofr.dev/pkg/gofr"
    "gofr.dev/pkg/gofr/container"
)

type User struct {
    ID    int32  `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

type UserResolver struct {
    user *User
}

func (r *UserResolver) ID() int32 {
    return r.user.ID
}

func (r *UserResolver) Name() string {
    return r.user.Name
}

func (r *UserResolver) Email() string {
    return r.user.Email
}

type MyResolver struct {
    Container *container.Container
}

// Resolver for the user query
func (r *MyResolver) User(args struct{ ID int32 }) (*UserResolver, error) {
    row := r.Container.SQL.QueryRow("SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE id = ?", args.ID)
    if row == nil {
        return nil, nil
    }

    var user User

    err := row.Scan(&user.Name, &user.Email)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    user.ID = int32(args.ID)
    return &UserResolver{user: &user}, nil
}

// Resolver for the addUser mutation
func (r *MyResolver) AddUser(args struct{ Name, Email string }) (*UserResolver, error) {
    result, err := r.Container.SQL.Exec("INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)", args.Name, args.Email)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    id, err := result.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    user := &User{ID: int32(int(id)), Name: args.Name, Email: args.Email}
    return &UserResolver{user: user}, nil
}

const schemaString = `
    type User {
        id: Int!
        name: String!
        email: String!
    }

    type Query {
        user(id: Int!): User!
    }

    type Mutation {
        addUser(name: String!, email: String!): User!
    }
`

func main() {
    // Create a new application
    a := gofr.New()

    // Register the updated GraphQL schema
    if err := a.RegisterGraphQLSchema(schemaString, func(container *container.Container) interface{} {
        return &MyResolver{Container: container}
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to register GraphQL schema: %v", err)
    }

    // Add all the routes
    a.GET("/hello", HelloHandler)

    // Run the application
    a.Run()
}

func HelloHandler(c *gofr.Context) (interface{}, error) {
    return "Hello, World!", nil
}

Code link: https://github.com/gofr-dev/gofr/blob/en/graphQL_support/examples/using-graphql-api/main.go
This example contains how to register the schema and resolver as well as a http handler.
But i want to simplify it further.
Is there any possibility that my graphQL resolvers can somehow match the signature of my http handlers, i know they are entirely different but the context contains all the support for tracing logging etc. With the current implementation it's hard to add these support as we don't have any access to context in the resolvers.
The container contains all the underlying db connections, inter-service calls etc. so that i have managed to do but also is there a better or more tidy way for that.
